# How to restrict swap space usage of application

Tags: linux, swap, limit, virtual-memory

We have a Java application hosted on (jetty server) running on CentOS machine.
Every second the application will handle thousands of websocket connections which will get opened and closed again.
Also this application makes NIO calls to get some data and send the data via websocket.

We have provided the XMS and XMS values for the application as 6gb
The machine on which the application is running has 16GB RAM.

The heap size is constant for the application, but the swap space is being shooted up to 4gb within 6-7 days after deployment.

After restart of the application the swap is becoming normal.

Is there any parameter which we can set to restrict the amount of usage of swap space by an application.

Is this issue related to large numbers of NIO operations?

In our case heap size is constant but native memory and swap space are being shooted up.

Could this be a possible memory leak or due to bug described [here](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6210541)?

Comment: No. Applications don't use swap space, the system does. Used swap space implies application memory usage. Do you track that?

Comment: How to track the usage of swap space by application? I feel the application is not returning the swap space back to OS.Any command/tool to track the usage?  When we were using g1gc alogrithm and using string de-duplication this swap usage was very less..when we are using CMS algorithm for garbage collection then swap usage is very high

Comment: Applications do not "get" or "give" swap space. If you have a second question, ask a second question. How would other users find the answer to "How to track. ." when the question and answer are indexed under "How to restrict ...".